# Component/LayoutManager to show a list of JPanels

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jpanel, layout-manager

Is there a way to show a list of `JPanels` and rearrange them? Creating a list could be done by using a `BoxLayout`, but how can you swap two `JPanels` then? It is also important that the panels stay interactive.

I'll try an example:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;

public class PanelList {

    private static final class Entry extends JPanel {

        public Entry(final int i) {
            super();
            final JButton button = new JButton("Dialog '" + i + "'");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Entry.this, "Hello World '"
                            + i + "'");
                }
            });
            this.add(button);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("PanelList");
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
                f.add(new BoxLayoutList());
                f.add(new JListList());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static final class BoxLayoutList extends JPanel {
        private final List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

        public BoxLayoutList() {
            this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10) {
                final Entry entry = new Entry(i);
                this.add(entry);
                this.entries.add(entry);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class JListList extends JPanel {
        private final DefaultListModel<Entry> entries = new DefaultListModel<>();

        public JListList() {
            final JList<Entry> entryComponent = new JList<>(this.entries);
            this.add(entryComponent);
            entryComponent.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer<Entry>() {
                @Override
                public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                        JList<? extends Entry> list, Entry value, int index,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                    return value;
                }
            });
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10) {
                final Entry entry = new Entry(i);
                this.entries.addElement(entry);
                i++;
            }
            // Example: Swap entries 4 and 2
            final Entry buffer = this.entries.get(4);
            this.entries.set(4, this.entries.get(2));
            this.entries.set(2, buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the BoxLayout is interactive but I don't know how to swap entries like I did with the entries 4 and 2 in the JList alternative. But there I'm impossible to interact with components.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `JList`<sup>1</sup> with drag'n'drop<sup>2</sup> reorder.

1. [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
2. [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer: Intro](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html)

Comment: I'm wondering what I doing wrong, because the UI isn't interactive.

Comment: So by *"the UI isn't interactive"* you actually mean *"the UI isn't coded"*?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with coded, so I try to explain: There are Buttons/CheckBoxes/ComboBoxes on the panel and I'm unable to use them (click on them, change the status). I was able to make an example which show two ways but both aren't quite the result I was searching for.

Comment: refrained from commenting yesterday ... assuming that the real requirement is "live" interaction :-) So using a list turned out to be a bit oversimplifying: @xZise if you need both real components and re-arranging by dnd there's no way around (that I see, at least) using a plain panel containing the entry-panels and implementing the dnd on that.

Comment: Okay drag and drop isn't so important. So it would be sufficient if you can move one panel down (and the panel below up). But I see no way to “switch” the position of two panels.

Answer (score 1):

from your comment it seems like we thought too complicated - if you want to *programmatically* exchange two children, all you need is

```
container.add(comp, index)
```

A quick snippet (crudest logic with hard-coded indices :)

```
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    panel.add(new JTextField("was at: " + i, 20));
}

Action action = new AbstractAction("exchange") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JTextField one = (JTextField) panel.getComponent(2);
        JTextField second = (JTextField) panel.getComponent(5);
        second.setText(second.getText() + " -> 2");
        one.setText(one.getText() + " -> 5");
        panel.add(second, 2);
        panel.add(one, 5);
        panel.revalidate();
    }

};
frame.add(new JButton(action), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```